# Find nearest location using strapi and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, strapi

I am using [Strapi V4](https://strapi.io/) and Postgres DB. So i have one table called `properties` where i am storing property details along with it's location as `geoLocation: [lat, lng]`.

what i want to do is, want to create one custom `POST` api, from where user's will provide their `[lat, lng]` and i want to find properties which are near to specified location from DB.

I haven't used `postgres` and `strapi` before and not sure either of them are providing any in-build geolocation methods.

can anyone give me any solution to this

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a distance function.  You can't use the Pythagorean theorem here because Earth is a sphere.  Even if you assume all your locations and users are in one cluster on Earth that's away from the poles, it still won't be right because a degree of latitude and a degree of longitude aren't the same distance except right on the Equator.  Hard-coding the conversion factor (to get the formula to work right in, e.g., London) is a recipe for bugs if and when your geographic assumptions ever change.

Distance (as the crow flies) on earth is what mathematicians call [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), so we can use one of the formulas for that metric:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
  earth_dist(a_lat NUMERIC(15,12), a_lng NUMERIC(15,12), 
               b_lat NUMERIC(15,12), b_lng NUMERIC(15,12))
RETURNS NUMERIC(8,3) AS $$

DECLARE
  cent_angle NUMERIC(8,7);

BEGIN
  a_lat := radians(a_lat);
  a_lng := radians(a_lng);
  b_lat := radians(b_lat);
  b_lng := radians(b_lng);

  cent_angle := acos(sin(a_lat)*sin(b_lat)+cos(a_lat)*cos(b_lat)*cos(a_lng - b_lng));

/* Multiply by radius of earth to get distances.  
Currently set to kilometers: change multiplier to use other units. */
  RETURN ROUND(6371*cent_angle,3);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

From there, I'm assuming in addition to collecting `lat` and `lng` you have some variable for the desired number of locations returned, say `num_rows`. To prevent SQL injection attacks, use the [PDO method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), storing these variables in a parameter list that's added separately.

Assuming that's done, you could write another function that returns a query, or just call it any other way:

```
SELECT property_id, property_name,
  earth_dist(:lat,:lng,property_lat,property_lng)
FROM properties
ORDER BY 3
LIMIT :num_rows;
```